# How to get `A^(-1/2)` in Python?

Tags: python

If I have a matrix

```
A=array([[ 0.59484625,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.58563893,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.58280472,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.58216725]])
```

How to get `A^(-1/2)`?

It seems that `linalg.matrix_power(D,-1/2)` does not work in Python.

In my opinion, `A^(-1/2)` is just

```
A=array([[ 0.59484625**(-1/2),  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.58563893**(-1/2),  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.58280472**(-1/2),  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.58216725**(-1/2)]])
```

But how to do that for a larger matrix?

Comment: Do you want the square root of the matrix pseudoinverse or element-wise to the -1/2 power?

Comment: Are you asking specifically how to do this for a diagonal matrix (where element-wise is equivalent to matrix-wise), or for any matrix?

Comment: @CJR I think that should be the (-1/2) power of the diagonal element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following :

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[ 0.59484625,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.58563893,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.58280472,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.58216725]])

d = np.diag(A)
D = np.array(d)
diagonal = np.diag(D**(-1/2))
print(diagonal)
```

**Note:** Because, when you try to calculate it directly 0^(-1/2) is an undetermined form .So, I firstly calculate the power of the diagonal then I convert it into a matrix .